# How can I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a UIViewController's didReceiveMemoryWarning?

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, didreceivememorywarning

I'm implementing didReceiveMemoryWarning in a subclass of UIViewController. My code looks something like the following:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    [self cleanUp];
}
```

When my app actually received a memory warning, the app crashed with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the `[self cleanUp]` line (a method that does exist). How could this happen? As I understand it, the framework called the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method, then released my class before it attempted to execute `[self cleanUp]`. Why would this happen? How can I prevent this?

Comment: That is bewildering. If it's alive enough to receive the didReceiveMemoryWarning message in the first place, why wouldn't it receive its own cleanUp message?!

Comment: Maybe your `-viewDidUnload` method is bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash was actually happening inside the `-(void)cleanUp` method, though Xcode was pointing to the line that **called** `[self cleanUp]`. Inside the `-(void)cleanUp` the code was accessing elements in an array that were already released, hence the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Thanks to all for the helpful suggestions.

Comment: It is always a good idea to set ivars to `nil` after you call `release`. You could skip this inside of `dealloc`, but guidelines without exceptions are easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing anything unusual in your view controller? What is the value of `self` when the crash occurs? Does it happen in both debug (optimization off) and release builds?

Try running with [NSZombieEnabled](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH7-SW3). If this is a problem with unbalanced retain/release, that should help you find it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - these were helpful in debugging my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: call [self cleanup] first, then call super.
You can also simulate memory warnings in the sim, if that helps.